# How do I put a circle with annotation in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, plot-annotations

I plot a graph created by networkx with matplotlib. Now, I'd like to add annotation to a specific node with a circle around. For instance,

[image]

I use [`plt.annotate(*args, **kwargs)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) with the following code,

```
# add annotate text
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
pos_annotation_node = pos['Medici']
ax2.annotate('Midici', 
            xy=pos_annotation_node, 
            xytext=(i+0.2 for i in pos_annotation_node),
            color='blue',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='blue', shrink=0.01)
        )
```

And I got this ugly graph,

[image]

I have two questions:

- how do I draw a circle around the node `6` as shown in first figure.
- to get a nice looking figure, I need manually set the value of `xytext` many times. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the [fancyarrow](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fancyarrow_demo.html) `arrowprops` syntax as demonstrated in [annotation_demo2](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/annotation_demo2.html), there is a `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` option that lets you shrink your arrow tail (`shrinkA`) and tip (`shrinkB`) independently, in points units.

Here's some arbitrary setup code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some data:
dat = np.array([[5, 3, 4, 4, 6],
                [1, 5, 3, 2, 2]])

# This is the point you want to point out
point = dat[:, 2]

# Make the figure
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 4))
plt.clf()
ax = plt.gca()
# Plot the data
ax.plot(dat[0], dat[1], 'o', ms=10, color='r')
ax.set_xlim([2, 8])
ax.set_ylim([0, 6])
```

And here is the code that puts a circle around one of these points and draws an arrow that is shrunk-back at the tip only:

```
circle_rad = 15  # This is the radius, in points
ax.plot(point[0], point[1], 'o',
        ms=circle_rad * 2, mec='b', mfc='none', mew=2)
ax.annotate('Midici', xy=point, xytext=(60, 60),
            textcoords='offset points',
            color='b', size='large',
            arrowprops=dict(
                arrowstyle='simple,tail_width=0.3,head_width=0.8,head_length=0.8',
                facecolor='b', shrinkB=circle_rad * 1.2)
)
```

Note here that:

1) I've made the marker face color of the circle transparent with `mfc='none'`, and set the circle size (diameter) to twice the radius.

2) I've shrunk the arrow by 120% of the circle radius so that it backs off of the circle just a bit. Obviously you can play with `circle_rad` and the value of `1.2` until you get what you want.

3) I've used the "fancy" syntax that defines several of the arrow properties in a string, rather than in the dict. As far as I can tell the `shrinkB` option is not available if you don't use the fancy arrow syntax.

4) I've used the `textcoords='offset points'` so that I can specify the position of the text relative to the point, rather than absolute on the axes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> how do I draw a circle around the node 6 as shown in first figure.

You get a center of node #6 (tuple `pos`). Use this data to set the blue circle position.

> to get a nice looking figure, I need manually set the value of xytext many times. Is there a better way?

Make a list of your labels and iterate in it and in tuples of coordinates of nodes to post annotate text. Look to comments of a code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
font = FontProperties()
font.set_weight('bold')
font.set_size('medium')

labels = ["Midici","Firenze"]

image = mpimg.imread("g.png") # just a image of your graph
plt.imshow(image)
ax = plt.gca()

# set your own radius and centers of circles in loop, like here
r = 11; c = (157,177)
circ1 = patches.Circle(c,2*r,lw=3.,ec='b',fill=False)
ax.add_artist(circ1)
circ1.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)

# annotate circles
# I have one circle but for your array pos_annotation_node
# you need 'i' to extract proper position
for i,label in enumerate(labels):
    annot_array_end = (c[0], c[1]+2*(-1)**i*r)
    annot_text_pos = (c[0]+3,c[1]+5*(-1)**i*r)
    ax.annotate(label, 
     xy= annot_array_end, 
     xytext=annot_text_pos,
     color='b',
     fontproperties=font,
     arrowprops=dict(fc='b', shrink=.005)
    )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just an observation for other people finding this thread. Not everything has to be done in Matplotlib.

It might well be easier to use a drawing package, with your network chart saved as a PDF (or PNG) in the background...